# Python list manipulation, multiple words in an entry

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of different movie genres:

`['Action, Adventure, Thriller', 'Comedy, Drama, Romance', 'Adventure, Drama, Romance', 'Crime, Drama', 'Drama, Thriller, War', 'Animation, Adventure, Comedy']`

The **first list entry 'Action, Adventure, Thriller'** consists of the genres of the first movie, **the second list entry 'Comedy, Drama, Romance'** consists of the genres of the second movie etc...

I want the following output in order to find out how often each genre appears in the list:

`['Action', 'Adventure', 'Thriller', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Adventure', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Thriller', 'War', 'Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']`

How could I achieve this list where each genre is **surrounded by single quotes and separated by comma?**

Comment: have you tried to loop through the list and split the string by `, ` ?

Comment: Yes but I had problems with the single quotes or unnecessary spaces, I don't know anymore. But my question was solved by Jilong Yin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import itertools


a = ['Action, Adventure, Thriller', 'Comedy, Drama, Romance', 'Adventure, Drama, Romance', 'Crime, Drama', 'Drama, Thriller, War', 'Animation, Adventure, Comedy']

b =[x.split(",") for x in a]

c = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(b))

# or if you can use 
d = [item for sublist in b for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked as intended!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your list is called **your_list**

```
[word.strip() for words in your_list for word in words.split(',')]
```